# How can I configure DOS and SQL Developer to use the TNSAMES file I want to use?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer to connect to a few Oracle databases on different versions i.e. 18.0.0 and 11.2.0.

I have installed both sets of drivers on my PC.  It appears that when I use TNSPING (via a command prompt); it uses the TNSNAMES file in the  18.0.0 folder and when I use the SQL Developer tool (https://www.oracle.com/uk/tools/downloads/sqldev-v192-downloads.html) it uses the TNSNAMES file in the 11.2.0 folder.

How can I configure DOS (TNSPING) and SQL Developer at runtime to use the TNSAMES file I want to use?

I have spent one hour Googling this, but I have not found an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two platforms, two different answers.

For 'DOS' - or say a command line interface running from the Oracle Client. SQLPlus is set to honor an ENV Var called TNS_ADMIN, but it will also check the ORACLE_HOME/network/admin folder, and it will also check the Windows Registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and Oracle, also for TNS_ADMIN.

For SQL Developer, a Java application using JDBC driver, it also tries to honor the TNS_ADMIN environment variable, although it does NOT go into the Windows Registry, looking for known TNSNames.ora files. It will also look in the current folder, or it will look where you TOLD it to look, in the application preferences.

You can see for yourself where SQL Developer is looking, but running this command through the script engine (F5)  -

```
show tns
```

This will show you what files we've found and are using, in addition to the first dozen or so services.

```
TNS Lookup locations
--------------------
1.  USER Home dir
    C:\Users\jdsmith

Location used:
-------------
    C:\Users\jdsmith

Available TNS Entries
---------------------
LISTENER_ORCL12C
ORCL
ORCL12C
```

If you want to tell SQLDev which tnsnames to use, look at the perferences

[image]

If you google 'tnsnames sql developer' the first couple of hits are StackOverflow questions that already cover this, and the [3rd one is to my blog](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/06/on-sql-developer-and-tnsnames-ora/).

Comment: The database is old - version 9.  Do I need a specific version of SQL Developer? +1.

Comment: you might get lucky, but we haven't supported version 9 in probably 10+ years